# How to solve the Error: Unknown named module: "../assets/images/image.jpeg", js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-hermes

In my json file, I have a list of projects with their corresponding images. But there is an error when I try to fetch the images.
ERROR  Error: Unknown named module: "../assets/images/image.jpeg", js engine: hermes

I removed require and tried with url. it worked. But not with the local images in my assets folder

Comment: can you provide code?